# desencriptar con cryptoJS

Tags: javascript, html5, encriptación

tengo el siguiente código para encriptar una palabra que la toma de un casillero login html, el caso es que quiero encriptarlo antes de guardarlo en una variable local, y luego en otra página tomar esa variable local encriptada y desencriptarla... así tengo los codigos

```js
function logueo(){
    var id=document.getElementById('mailoId').value;
    var pagina="2.html";

    
        if(id=="FULANITO"){
            guardarID=encriptado(id);

            console.log("return de la funcion en el if: "+ guardarID);
            localStorage.setItem("quienEntra", guardarID);  

        }
        
        var btn = document.getElementById('formulario');
        // Setting new attributes
    btn.setAttribute("action", "2.html");

}


function encriptado(id){

var encript=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(id,pwAES);

return encript;

}
```

luego en otro script distinto (para el caso da igual) obtengo el localStorage pero no me deja desencriptarlo, usando la misma variable key

```js
var quienseLoquea=localStorage.getItem("quienEntra");//obtengo el item guardado de quien ha entrado
console.log("quienseLoguea: "+quienseLoquea);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(quienseLoquea, pwAES);
console.log("decrypted: "+decrypted);

var quienseLoqueadesencriptado=decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("quienseLoguea decrypted to string: "+quienseLoqueadesencriptado);
```

el error es:
Uncaught ReferenceError: encript is not defined

este es el del encriptado que va al login.html

```html
var pwAES = "v9y$B&E)H@McQfTjWmZq4t7w!z%C*F-J"; var guardarID="asd" function logueo(){ var id=document.getElementById('mailoId').value; var pagina="2.html"; console.log("dentro de la funcion logueo"); console.log("dentro del primer if"); if(id=="doc0@iapps"){ guardarID=encriptado(id); console.log("return de la funcion en el if: "+ guardarID); localStorage.setItem("quienEntra", guardarID); } } function encriptado(id){ var encript=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(id,pwAES); return encript; }
```

este es el otro script que va despues del login.html a una html nueva

```html
var pwAES = "v9y$B&E)H@McQfTjWmZq4t7w!z%C*F-J"; var quienseLoquea="" //const CryptoJS = require ('crypto-js'); // referencia al código fuente AES js var quienseLoquea=localStorage.getItem("quienEntra");//obtengo el item guardado de quien ha entrado console.log("quienseLoguea: "+quienseLoquea); var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(quienseLoquea, pwAES); console.log("palabra descriptada: "+decrypted); var finencript=decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); console.log("palabra descriptada final: "+finencript);
```

Comment: Todo parece bien,  solo verifica que no tengas una variable  `en cript` (no referenciada) en el otro archivo

Comment: lo que pasa es que si hago la encriptación y desdencriptación dentro de una misma funcion, funciona correctamente, pero si saco de esa funcion la desencriptación y lo añado a otra función, ya me salta ese fallo...

Comment: El error te dice que hay una variable no definida que se llama `encript` verifica eso

Comment: si, pero no lo entiendo :S
Uncaught ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined
que no está definido cryptoJS lo entiendo pero si en el primer script funciona bien(llama a la funcion que encripta), la segunda funcion que quiero realizar es el desencriptado, pero llamando al localstorage donde está la palabra encriptada, cargo esa palabra en una variable, y a continuación (estoy hablando de que estoy en otro archivo intentando desencriptar esa palabra) llamo a lo segundo que he puesto mas arriba en la consulta.


y ahí es donde no me funciona el desencriptado

Comment: En ambos archivos tienes que importar todo igual que en el primer archivo, si tienes problemas copia y pega el mismo código y en el segundo archivo elimina la función encriptsr

Comment: en el primer archivo funciona bien, encripto y desencripto
en el segundo pongo:
var quienseLoquea=localStorage.getItem("quienEntra");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(quienseLoquea, pwAES);
console.log("palabra descriptada: "+decrypted);

var finencript=decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("palabra descriptada final: "+finencript);
y es cuando me sale el error en la linea "var decrypted)

Comment: Ahí te sale `Uncaught ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined` ?

Comment: Si estas importando la librería?

Comment: exacto, en esa linea sale ese error, y si pongo 
const CryptoJS = require ('crypto-js');  me sale:
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Mmm... que rato, si en el 0rimer archivo no te error, tampoco te lo bebería dar en el segundo (si haces las cosas igual)

Comment: puede ser que la variable con el texto encriptado (tomado del localstorage) sea texto plano o algo por el estilo?

Comment: El error te lo da al importar la librería, no al desencriptar, de igual forma lo que se almacena en el localstorage se aomacena en texto plano

Comment: pues no entiendo, en los dos html (en el que encripto y en el que desencripto) tengo importado lo mismo 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>

y en el js de desencriptar es lo mismo

Comment: Podrias mostrar todo el código de ambos archivos (js)

Comment: este es el del encriptado que va al login.html

var pwAES = "v9y$B&E)H@McQfTjWmZq4t7w!z%C*F-J";
var guardarID="asd"

function logueo(){
 var id=document.getElementById('mailoId').value;
 var pagina="2.html";

 console.log("dentro de la funcion logueo");



  console.log("dentro del primer if");
  if(id=="doc0@iapps"){
   guardarID=encriptado(id);

   console.log("return de la funcion en el if: "+ guardarID);
   localStorage.setItem("quienEntra", guardarID); 

  }

 }

function encriptado(id){

var encript=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(id,pwAES);

return encript;

}

Comment: este es el otro script que va despues del login.html a una html nueva

var pwAES = "v9y$B&E)H@McQfTjWmZq4t7w!z%C*F-J";
var quienseLoquea=""
//const CryptoJS = require ('crypto-js'); // referencia al código fuente AES js


var quienseLoquea=localStorage.getItem("quienEntra");//obtengo el item guardado de quien ha entrado
console.log("quienseLoguea: "+quienseLoquea);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(quienseLoquea, pwAES);
console.log("palabra descriptada: "+decrypted);

var finencript=decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("palabra descriptada final: "+finencript);

Comment: edita tu pregunta por favor

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO

al final es por que mi scrip .js estaba cargandose en el html antes que

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

por lo que no podía hacer la llamada a sus funciones.